# Order of an ideal in class group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $m$ be a positive integer such that $m \equiv 6 \mod 8$. I will write $[a,b]$ for the lattice $a\mathbb{Z} \oplus b\mathbb{Z}$. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be the ring $[1,4\sqrt{-m}]$ and $\mathfrak{a} = [4,1+\sqrt{-m}]$ which is a fractional ideal of $\mathcal{O}$. We assume that $\mathfrak{a}$ is invertible.

I want to show that $\mathfrak{a}$ has order $4$ in $C(\mathcal{O})$ (the class group of $\mathcal{O}$) i.e. that $\mathfrak{a}^4$ is principal and that$\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{a}^2,\mathfrak{a}^3$ are not. Somehow I feel it should be easy and yet I have been picking my brain for $4$ hours already so I guess I must be missing something.

This is not homework just independent study so I would not mind a complete answer.

Comment: I'm confused about $\cal O$ and $\frak a$. How is $1+\sqrt{-m}\in {\bf Z}+ 4\sqrt{-m}{\bf Z}$?

Comment: @anon, a *fractional* ideal of a ring is not necessarily a subset of the ring.

Comment: anton, can you calculate the 4th power of that fractional ideal? What do you get?

Comment: It's a fractionnal ideal i.e. it's a rank $2$ $\mathcal{O}$-submodule of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-m})$ such that there exists $a \in \mathcal{O}$ such that $a \mathfrak{a} \subset \mathcal{O}$ in this case $a=4$ works.

Comment: that's the thing. I'm a little bit ashamed to admit it but i'm not really sure of how to compute $\mathfrak{a}^2$. In my mind it's something like $(16,4(1+\sqrt{-m}),1-m+2\sqrt{-m})$ but i'm confused with the lattice notation. Also I don't know what is the canonical form to put it in that allows you to decide wether or not it is principal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One has from definition that

$$
{\bigg(}a,b{\bigg)}{\bigg(}c,d{\bigg)}={\bigg(}ac,ad,bc,bd{\bigg)} 
$$

To clarify your ideas on lattice notation, note that ${\mathfrak a}=[4,1+\sqrt{-m}]={\bigg(}4,1+\sqrt{-m}{\bigg)}$ (in general,
we only have an inclusion $[a,b] \subseteq {\bigg(}a,b{\bigg)}$ since in fact
${\bigg(}a,b{\bigg)}=[a,b,4a\sqrt{-m},4b\sqrt{-m}]$, but the reverse inclusion
is easy to check here).

Note also that once you have that ${\mathfrak a}^4$ is principal and
${\mathfrak a}^2$ is not, you needn’t consider ${\mathfrak a}^3$. Because 
then the order of $\mathfrak a$ in the class group can only be $2$.

With that in mind, we can now compute :

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathfrak a}^2 &=& 
{\bigg(}4,1+\sqrt{-m}{\bigg)}{\bigg(}4,1+\sqrt{-m}{\bigg)} \\
&=& {\bigg(}16,4(1+\sqrt{-m}),4(1+\sqrt{-m}),1-m+2\sqrt{-m}{\bigg)} \\
&=& {\bigg(}16,4(1+\sqrt{-m}),1-m+2\sqrt{-m}{\bigg)} \\
&=& {\bigg(}16,4(1+\sqrt{-m})-2(1-m+2\sqrt{-m}),1-m+2\sqrt{-m}{\bigg)} \\
&=& {\bigg(}16,4-2(1-m),1-m+2\sqrt{-m}{\bigg)} \\
&=& {\bigg(}16,2(1+m),1-m+2\sqrt{-m}{\bigg)} \\
&=& {\bigg(}16,2(8k+7),1-m+2\sqrt{-m}{\bigg)} \\
&=& {\bigg(}16,16(k+1)-2(8k+7),1-m+2\sqrt{-m}{\bigg)} \\
&=& {\bigg(}2,1-m+2\sqrt{-m}{\bigg)} \\
&=& {\bigg(}2,1+2\sqrt{-m}{\bigg)} \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

and

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathfrak a}^4 &=& 
{\bigg(}2,1+2\sqrt{-m}{\bigg)}{\bigg(}2,1+2\sqrt{-m}{\bigg)} \\
&=& {\bigg(}4,2(1+2\sqrt{-m}),1-4m+4\sqrt{-m}{\bigg)} \\
&=& {\bigg(}4,2+4\sqrt{-m},1-4m+4\sqrt{-m}{\bigg)} \\
&=& {\bigg(}4,2+4\sqrt{-m},1-4m+4\sqrt{-m}-(2+4\sqrt{-m}){\bigg)} \\
&=& {\bigg(}4,2+4\sqrt{-m},-1-4m{\bigg)} \\
&=& {\bigg(}4,1+4m,2+4\sqrt{-m}{\bigg)} \\
&=& {\bigg(}1,\ldots{\bigg)} = {\mathcal O}. \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

So ${\mathfrak a}^4$ is certainly principal. Suppose by contradition that ${\mathfrak a}^2$ were principal, say ${\mathfrak a}^2={\bigg(}g{\bigg)}$ for some $g\in{\mathcal a}^2$. there are integers $x,y$ such that $g=2x+y(1+2\sqrt{-m})$.

Then $g$ divides both $2$ and $1-m+2\sqrt{-m}$ in $\mathcal O$. Write
$g=g_1+g_2\sqrt{-m}$ where $g_1=2x+y$ and $g_2=2y$.

Then ,there must exist integers $g_3,g_4,g_5,g_6$ with

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
((2x+y)+2y\sqrt{-m})(g_3+4g_4\sqrt{-m})=2, \\
((2x+y)+2y\sqrt{-m})(g_5+4g_6\sqrt{-m})=1-m+2\sqrt{-m}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

which is equivalent to

$$
\Bigg\lbrace
\begin{eqnarray}
(2x+y)g_3-8myg_4&=&2 \\
2yg_3+4(2x+y)g_4&=&0 \\
(2x+y)g_5-8myg_6&=&1-m \\
2yg_5+4(2x+y)g_6&=&2 \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

We see from the third line that $yg_5$ is odd. So both $y$ and $g_5$
are odd, and from the first line we see then that $g_3$ is even, say $g_3=2h_3$. Then

$$
\Bigg\lbrace
\begin{eqnarray}
(2x+y)h_3-4myg_4&=&1 \\
yh_3+(2x+y)g_4&=&0 \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

The second line informs us that $y$ divides $2xg_4$. Since $y$ is coprime
to both $2$ and $x$, by Gauss’ lemma we have that $y$ divides $g_4$, so
$g_4=yh_4$ for some integer $h_4$. Then

$$
\Bigg\lbrace
\begin{eqnarray}
(2x+y)h_3-4my^2h_4&=&1 \\
h_3+(2x+y)h_4&=&0 \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

and we finally obtain $-h_4((2x+y)^2+4my^2)=1$ which is clearly impossible
(just look at the signs).

Comment: wow thanks ! great answer